# How to set equal horizontal spacing between UIfields

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

layouts and i have added 5 button on my view-controller and here i have applied constant width and height for all 5 fields

Here my main requirement is i want to set equal horizontal spacing between all fields and

For this i have fit for constraint For "middle button"

1)topspace
2)width
3)height
4)center horizontal in container

For "fist button"

1)topspace
2)width
3)height
4)leading space

For fifth button:-

1)topspace
2)trailing
3)width
4)height

For second and Fourth buttons i have given 1)top space,width,height,horizontal spacing but they are not setting perfectly please help me screen is coming like first image

[image]

but i want fit that screen like second image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start out by setting each one of your views to have a constant width, let's say that it's 40. So every view now has a width of 40.

Now you need to place a leading/trailing constraint on your furthest left/right view to the superview (This is assuming you want the furthest left/right view to have a static distance from the left/right superview).

Now go ahead and create a horizontal constraint from your furthest left view to the second one in. Create a horizontal constraint from the second to the third. Then make a horizontal constraint from the furthest right view to the fourth. Now the fourth to the third.

What you should now do is edit the four horizontal constraints you have created by changing their value to not being "= constant", but ">= constant". Now you can lower that constant value to help adjust for smaller screen sizes as well. This setup should provide the result that you're looking for by having all of the views equally distanced, while letting the left and right view be closer to the sides.

Comment: you do i have to change priority Low(250) please explain clearly

Comment: You don't necessarily need to change the priority. Just change the constant value from being "=" to ">="

Comment: i am completely new for auto-layouts can you cut and post the related screen where i have to change in xcode or can i also cnange that in viewdidLoad method if possible how to chnage please explain me Jonathan thanks and regrad's